# Insert another view in next row on cell click in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using collection view controller to show image gallery with thumbnail. 
Currently I have 3 images per row.
When I click on any thumbnail, I want to show bigger image of the cell in the next row.
So next row should slide down, and an image with large view should come up.
When again I click on the cell, bigger image should disappear and next row should slid up to original position.

I simply created storyboard with CollectionViewController and bind to array of images. It displays all the images in CollectionViewCell perfectly. I want to achieve functionality in second image (please check image at https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8h1hg4629fd8zx/requirement.png)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to show your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Wezly, 
I simply created storyboard with CollectionViewController and bind to array of images. It displays all the images in CollectionViewCell perfectly. I want to achieve functionality in second image (please check image at https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8h1hg4629fd8zx/requirement.png)